# Contar un Array donde un atributo empiece por

Tags: javascript, array, angular

estoy intentando hacer un método que me cuente el número de elementos que tiene un Array que empiece por "RT:"

Para ello he desarrollado el siguiente código:

```
public getRowsRTs(idProyecto){

    this.twitterService.getTargets().subscribe((data) => {

      this.Twitter = data;

    });

    let countRT = this.Twitter.filter( tweet => tweet.mensaje.startsWith("RT:")).length;

    return countRT;

  }
}
```

Aquí, data me devuelve todos los Documentos que extrae Mongo, y me los mete en el Array de Twitter que tengo definido al principio del componente. Dentro de este Array cada elemento tiene diferentes atributos, como son _id, mensaje, fecha... yo lo que pretendo es que me cuente cuantos de esos documentos, el valor de mensaje, comienza por RT: y que me lo devuelva, este código, no me da ningún problema, pero no me devuelve absolutamente nada, no sé si alguien me podría ayudar.

Comment: Te enfrentas a problemas de asincronía, el método `this.twitterService.getTargets()` es asíncrono y por lo tanto usas `subscribe()` para capturar la info cuando esta esté disponible. Sin embargo, luego de hacer el llamado a dicho método, llamas a la función `filter` y eso ocurre cuando los datos aún no han sido obtenidos por tu servicio. ¿Qué tal si mueves las 2 lineas que tienes fuera del `subscribe` dentro del mismo? Si bien pudiera funcionar, falta contexto para decirte si esa es una solución real al problema. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras lo he probado y no ha funcionado, gracias!

Comment: Claro, como te digo falta contexto, pero lo que intuyo es que tu servicio devuelve un `Observable`, por lo tanto, una vez que el mismo recibe datos podrás trabajar con ellos sólo dentro del `callback` que pasas al método `subscribe()`. Si lo que deseas es tener esos datos disponibles al cargar el componente, has de llamar a tu función dentro de `ngOnInit()`. Pero como te dije anteriormente, sin un contexto más amplio de lo que pretendes hacer, es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Correcto, llevas razon, la petición se pasa mediante un Observable